# If I wanted to run a Monero node would I be able to limit the number of inbound connections?

Tags: monerod, full-node, monerod-commands

I remember trying to set one up before and one of the issues I had was trying to limit the number of inbound connections.

edit: by connections, I am referring to the number of peers connected at one time

Comment: Can you clarify that you really want to limit the number of inbound connections instead of the amount of inbound traffic? https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/does-each-node-have-a-maximum-number-of-peers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

monerod currently can only be set to limit outgoing connections with the parameter `--out-peers` where the default is 8.

So if you setup your node to be reachable for the public, you can't limit incoming connections. However, you could use a firewall like [iptables](https://serverfault.com/questions/371763/limit-maximum-incoming-connections-to-a-port-using-iptables) to limit incoming connections on your public port.