# What is the maximum number of incoming connections by default? 0 or unlimited?

Tags: network, p2p, peer-discovery, peer

Based on [this question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/does-each-node-have-a-maximum-number-of-peers) in 2016, there is no limit on the number of incoming connections. However, based on [this commit](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/commit/32c0f908cd753f9319909e2f43d2b4657ebaf664#diff-716a5cc98aa851883a68a864b2d6495c) in 2018, users can set a limit for this number.

By default, when I don't set any limit for the **arg_in_peers** via RPC command, the value will be -1. Does this mean my node cannot accept any incoming connection, or there will be no limit on this number? In other words, what is the default value of **max_in_connection_count**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value for in-peers is -1 (unlimited). The reason -1 is (in effect) unlimited is because `max_in_connection_count` is an *unsigned integer* and therefore 0-1 wraps to the maximum of an uint32_t (i.e. `2^32-1`).

If you need to limit the inbound connections, set `in-peers=N` (replacing N with the number of incoming peers to allow) in your daemon config.